# Problems in running MakeFile

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, terminal

I am trying to learn/use [inject_and_interpose](https://github.com/comex/inject_and_interpose) project.

I am facing problems with [make file](https://github.com/comex/inject_and_interpose/blob/master/tester/Makefile). When I try to execute make file on terminal, I get following error message.

```
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: ?=: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: gcc: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
ARCH: Can't find any plists for ARCH
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
./Makefile: line 3: findstring: command not found
./Makefile: line 3: ifeq: command not found
ARCH: Can't find any plists for ARCH
./Makefile: line 5: endif: command not found
./Makefile: line 7: all:: command not found
./Makefile: line 9: testlib.dylib:: command not found
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
ARCH: Can't find any plists for ARCH
./Makefile: line 10: -dynamiclib: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: tester:: command not found
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
./Makefile: line 12: -O3: command not found
./Makefile: line 13: testputs:: command not found
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
./Makefile: line 14: -o: command not found
./Makefile: line 15: clean:: command not found
rm: tester: is a directory
```

Can somebody please explain me what changes I have do to run this make file properly? Or Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: How are you "executing" the make file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makefiles are not intended to be run by sh or friends. You invoke it by running

```
$ make
```

in the directory the makefile is in.